# FileTransfer error code 1 with http_status 404

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, file-transfer

Im trying to upload file using filetransfer but it works sometime and fails most of the time with response error code 1 and 404 http_status, body containing html code.

Comment: what do you mean by "body containing html code"?

Comment: What you have tried so far? And also, please specify used plugin for FileTransfer.

Comment: Are you using for loop?

Comment: Im using https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/  . Now i observe that if uploadUrl is given as https:// it fails with the above error. But with http:// it works prefectly fine.

Comment: @bharathv, you may have to look at the "trustAllHosts" optional parameter available in file transfer plugin. Extracte from plugin page - trustAllHosts: Optional parameter, defaults to false. If set to true, it accepts all security certificates. This is useful since Android rejects self-signed security certificates. Not recommended for production use. Supported on Android and iOS. (boolean)

Comment: I will check it once. Then what would be the solution for production?

Comment: @bharathv: In production, you may have to use certificate issued and verified by a trusted Certificate Authority instead of self signed certificates